# Utilizing state/customState with passport-azure-ad

Tags: node.js, openid-connect, adal, azure-ad-b2c, passport-azure-ad

I'm having trouble figuring out the purpose of `customState` and if/how I can utilize it to pass data to the return url. Specifically I wish to route the user back to their original location after being signed in. I thought I could pass the original url to the parameter `customState` and have it returned back to me in the return url `POST`, but it appears to be encoded or perhaps replaced with a different value.

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Anonymous user visits `/page/protected` which requires authentication.
2. Code calls `passport.authenticate` which in turn redirects the user to sign in.
3. User signs in and is returned to the pre-configured return url e.g.: `/auth/oidc/return`.
4. Code handles extracting information from form-post data.
5. User is directed back to `/page/protected`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A return URL (e.g. "/page/protected") can be round-tripped by:

1) Setting the "customState" parameter before the authentication middleware redirects to Azure AD B2C:

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
    response: res,
    resourceURL: config.resourceURL,
    customState: '/page/protected', // Or set to the current URL
    failureRedirect: '/'
  })(req, res, next);
}, function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

2) Getting the `req.body.state` parameter after the authentication middleware validates the authentication response from Azure AD B2C:

```
app.post('/auth/openid/return', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
    response: res,
    failureRedirect: '/'
  })(req, res, next);
}, function (req, res) {
  res.redirect(req.body.state);
});
```

The "customState" parameter value should be encrypted, which will mean the `req.body.state` parameter will have to be decrypted, if you don't want the return URL to be tampered with.

Otherwise, it is common to write the return URL to `req.session` before the authentication middleware redirects and sends the authentication request to Azure AD B2C, and then read (and then delete) this return URL from `req.session` after the authentication middleware receives and validates the authentication response from Azure AD B2C.

Comment: I've found this as well, but I would prefer to not start a session unless the user actually logs in. Was hoping there was a way to do that.

Comment: Hi @Thomas. I've updated the above answer with how the return URL can be round- tripped using the "state" parameter.

Comment: Thanks! There was "something" in my code that messed with the returned state in some way (or prevented my state string from being added to the actual b2c request). Cleaning up my code and using your example I was able to get it working. Thanks a million!