# Problem with OIDCStrategy passport-azure-ad passport js?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js, adal, passport-azure-ad

I am using the https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad plugin to work with the Azure AD Graph API.

Dependency in my package.json

`"passport-azure-ad": "^3.0.12"`

I have refered samle provided here: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS

I am able to do `auth` & get `access_token` & `refresh_token`. But the last argument done is giving an error as

```
TypeError: done is not a function
```

My code is written using Typescript my strategy code:

```
  passport.use( new OIDCStrategy( {
    identityMetadata: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantName + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    clientID: clientID,
    responseType: app_properties.responseType,
    responseMode: app_properties.responseMode,
    redirectUrl: app_properties.redirectUrl,
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl: app_properties.allowHttpForRedirectUrl,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    validateIssuer: app_properties.validateIssuer,
    isB2C: app_properties.isB2C,
    issuer: app_properties.issuer,
    passReqToCallback: app_properties.passReqToCallback,
    scope: app_properties.scope,
    loggingLevel: app_properties.loggingLevel,
    nonceLifetime: app_properties.nonceLifetime,
    nonceMaxAmount: app_properties.nonceMaxAmount,
    useCookieInsteadOfSession: app_properties.useCookieInsteadOfSession,
    cookieEncryptionKeys: app_properties.cookieEncryptionKeys,
    clockSkew: app_properties.clockSkew
  },
    function ( iss: any, sub: any, profile: any, accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, done: any ) {

      if ( iss ) {
        console.log( 'iss' + JSON.stringify( iss ) );
      }

      if ( sub ) {
        console.log( 'sub' + JSON.stringify( sub ) );
      }

      if ( accessToken ) {
        console.log( 'Received accessToken ' + accessToken );
      }

      if ( refreshToken ) {
        console.log( 'Received refreshToken ' + refreshToken );
      }
      if ( !profile.oid ) {
        console.log( 'Received accessToken ' + accessToken );
        return done( new Error( "No oid found" ), null );
      }

      if ( profile ) {
        console.log( 'profile' + JSON.stringify( profile ) );
      }

      return done(null, profile);
    } ) );
```

Also, the custom state parameter does not retain state string, As per documentation

```
customState: if you want to use a custom state value instead of a randomly generated one
```

Why `done` is not working? Also, how can I maintain state?

Below is redirection URL invocation endpoint function in my app server

```
export function authAzureAd( req: Request, res: Response, next: any ) {
passport.authenticate( 'azuread-openidconnect' , function ( err: any, user: any, info: any ) {
              if ( err ) {
                return next( err );
              }
              if ( !user ) {
                return res.send( { success: false, message: 'authentication failed' } );
              }
              console.info( 'user: ' + JSON.stringify( user ) );
              return res.send( { success: true, message: 'authentication succeeded' } );
            } )( req, res, next );
} catch ( err ) {
    console.info( err );
    res.status( 500 ).send( { message: err.message } );
  }
}
```

Auth Callback POST API endpoint function call as follows:

```
export function authCallback(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) {
  console.info('In the AzureAD callback, next = '+next);
  if (next == null) { // If we want something else to happen here, we can do it
    next = () => {};
  }
  try {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login', customState: 'my_state', successRedirect: '/dashboard' })(req, res, next)
  } catch (err) {
    console.info(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
  }
}
```

**Update**

1] About `TypeError: done is not a function` I updated the package.json to have dependency as `"passport-azure-ad": "4.0.0"` instead of `"passport-azure-ad": "^3.0.12"` then `done` started working with `process.nextTick()` as defined in sample verify callback in [the documentation.](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#5111-sample-using-the-oidcstrategy)

2] About `customState` I get the state param in the `req.body.state` not in `req.query.state`. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793615/utilizing-state-customstate-with-passport-azure-ad) The reason for this the auth callback by azure-ad happens to be HTTP POST not HTTP GET like in other OAuth flows. Hence the state is part of the body.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

1] About `TypeError: done is not a function` I updated the package.json to have dependency as `"passport-azure-ad": "4.0.0"` instead of `"passport-azure-ad": "^3.0.12"` then `done` started working with `process.nextTick()` as defined in sample verify callback in [the documentation.](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#5111-sample-using-the-oidcstrategy)

2] About `customState` I get the state param in the `req.body.state` not in `req.query.state`. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793615/utilizing-state-customstate-with-passport-azure-ad) The reason for this the auth callback by azure-ad happens to be HTTP POST not HTTP GET like in other OAuth flows. Hence the state is part of the body.