# Landing page is not as requested after login with azure ad

Tags: authentication, redirect, azure-active-directory

When I visit `https://example.com/products` when not logged in, it's going to Azure ad login form then it's sent to `https://example.com/` automatically. I am not able to store the original requested URL.

The flow I want to implement:

When an unauthorized user enters `https://example.com/testId=123`

Redirect to Azure AD authentication page and login success

Return to `https://example.com/testId=123`

Comment: refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793615/utilizing-state-customstate-with-passport-azure-ad/69970369#69970369). It might help u, it helped me

Answer (score 1):

#### Redirect to the static URI

You can set the `Redirect URI` with the specific page in the portal, then in your authentication URL, specify the `redirect_uri` with that page, it will redirect to the page after authentication.

1. Navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> select your app in `App registrations` -> `Authentication`, set the redirect URL
   e.g. `https://example.azurewebsites.net/callback.html`

   [image]
2. In your authorization URL, set the `redirect_uri` with https://test.azurewebsites.net/callback.html (url encoded), note the url must be one of the Redirect URIs in the portal.

#### Redirect to the dynamic URI

Redirect to dynamic URI, Azure AD doesn't support it. Reference: [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#redirect-uris-can-now-contain-query-string-parameters)

> Azure AD applications can now register and use redirect (reply) URIs with static query parameters (such as https://contoso.com/oauth2?idp=microsoft) for OAuth 2.0 requests. Dynamic redirect URIs are still forbidden as they represent a security risk, and this cannot be used to retain state information across an authentication request - for that, use the state parameter.

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817811/azure-ad-authentication-return-to-previous-page-with-parameter-after-login)